# Standard user interface for QGIS plugins

Tags: qgis, python, gui

QGIS plugins found in "processing" all have the same user interface.
In particular, to open a file, the selector either show the list of already downloaded files, or have a "..." button to browse and load a file, which will replace the list of files.

I could (painfully) rewrite this code, but I'm wondering if there are some ready-made code to generate this kind of "standard" user interface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you may explore these modules:

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/tree/master/python/plugins/processing/gui

you should import with:

```
from processing.gui import <what you want>
```

and gui use can be read directly from the processing plugin code

regards